# Ruby on Rails on Docker - Passenger vs Puma vs Unicorn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

What are the Pros/Cons of using Passenger, Unicorn or Puma to serve a RoR app when it is running as a docker container?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the container matters so much.  Puma seems the thing to use nowadays.